# Remove unwanted characters from a log file

Tags: python, regex, shell

I am writing a Python script to read in a file, read through that file line by line and parse out data from that file to another text file via user command line argument. I am close to finish but my log file have some weird characters "^@" that I do not want to include in my output file.

temp.log:

```
06 May 19 03:40:35^@ 3 abCodeClearTrap Error Clear Trap (agent: 12367a12,
chassis:12367a12, ErrIdText: ERROR ID TEXT, csssi: EXTIFG, clearedID:
0x089088394)

06 May 19 03:44:35^@ 3 abCodeErrorTrap Error Trap (agent: 12368a15,
chassis:12368a15, ErrIdText: Skip this item, csssi: SSRSSR, clearedID:
0x089088394)
```

My code:

```
import re, sys

with open('temp.log') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()

with open('output.txt') as o:

    data = []
    for line in lines:
       if 'date' in sys.argv:
           try:
              date = re.match(r'\date{2} \w+ \date{2}', line).group()
              row.append(date)
           except:
              date = 'date'
       if 'time' in sys.argv:
           try:
               time = line.split()[3]
               row.append(time)
               lst = [x.replace("^@","") for x in lst]
               row.append(",")
           except:
               time = 'time'
       if 'agent' in sys.argv:
           try:
              agent = re.search(r'agent:\s(.*?),', line).group()
              row.append(agent)
           except:
              agent = 'agent:'
       if 'err' in sys.argv:
           try:
              errID = re.search(r'ErrIdText:\s(.*?),', line).group()
              row.append(errID)
           except:
              errID = 'ErrIdText:'
       if 'clear' in sys.argv:
           try:
              clear = re.search(r'clearedID:\s(.*?)\)', line).group()
              row.append(clear)
           except:
              clear = 'clearedID:'

       row = []
       data.append(row)

     for row in data:
        lines = o.writelines(row)
        lines = o.writelines("\n")
        print(row)

     o.close()
```

I tried to replace in my if that dealing with time but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: try to run `replace("^@","")` on the `line` iteration variable before doing anything else

Comment: @Francesco Boi: Actually since `lines` is a string holding the entire file's contents, the OP could just do a `lines.replace(("^@","")` _once_ right before the `for line in lines:` loop.

Comment: @martineau could you please show me in code?

Comment: petelam: I did, just add that one line before the `for line in lines:`.

Comment: I did that and got Attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Your patterns are a mess: `r'\date{2} \w+ \date{2}'` matches a digit with `\d`, then must come `at`, then `ee` (as `e{2}` matches two consecutive `e`s), then a space...

Comment: petelam: Sorry, missed that you were using `readlines()`—so instead of adding that line, further up _change_ the `lines = f.readlines()` statement to `lines = f.read().replace("^@", "").splitlines()`.

Comment: I found out that "^@" is a special vim NULL byte so i am not sure if replace work in this case. @martineau

Comment: petelam: In that case use `replace("\x00", "")`.